# Preserve Evil state when jumping between org-edit-special and org-mode

Tags: org-mode, evil

When executing `C-'` (`org-edit-special`) it always starts in normal evil state even if I am in insert state originally. Same when jumping back, if I am in normal state then it switches back to the original state before jumping.
How to preserve state when jumping between special editing and org-mode in Evil?

Comment: Why don't you just unconditionally change the state for editing by using a hook? Preserving it is too much trouble IMO.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Did you mean preserve it even when opening new files? That would actually be troubling to me as some files I am editing and other would be only for navigation and browsing. Is it not possible to only preserve it when doing org-edit-special? I think of it as a narrow, it preserves the state as if it is accessing the same part of the file.

Comment: Don't interpret things there I didn't write. All I'm asking here is whether you've considered to unconditionally change to insert state for editing, like by using `org-src-mode-hook`. This is how things are done for minor modes typically, where customizing the initial state wouldn't work.

Comment: I see. That would still not work for me. Sometimes I just navigate the code but like it to be in org-edit-special to isolate the code or do some indentation, or some simple processing doable from normal state.